# Pl/SQL IFS Custom Field

Tags: sql, oracle

This is ONE Instance of number format, in this format 558.02 is common to all instance, that’s the output for this format.

```
558.02 
558.02.01 
558.02.02 
558.02.07 
558.02.08 
558.02.06
```

This another number instance format, in this format 555 is common to all instances, that’s the output for this format.

```
555 
555.01 
555.04
```

My table name sk_task_tab
task_seq number is unique. Above number instance are object_id

task_seq can have many object_

I want to select a common number set when providing a task_seq number.

In my scenario, there can be a third dot(.) it can have a fourth dot(.) as well or there can be no dot scenarios as well.

This should be a SQL select query without declaring variables.

I want to get a common number set when providing a task_seq. This should be a PLSQL select query without declaring variables. Because cannot declare variables where I am going to add this code.

Answer (score 0):

Split each string up into the individual terms and then aggregate by the term's index within the string and check that in all the values there is only a single term and then you can find the terms with consecutive indexes starting from 1 (as there may be a term which is common to all the rows but is not consecutive with the other common terms at the start of the sequence):

```sql
WITH term_bounds (task_seq_no, value, idx, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT task_seq_no,
         value,
         1,
         1,
         INSTR(value, '.', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT task_seq_no,
         value,
         idx + 1,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, '.', epos + 1)
  FROM   term_bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
),
terms (task_seq_no, term, idx) AS (
  SELECT task_seq_no,
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - spos)
         END,
         idx
  FROM   term_bounds
),
common_terms (task_seq_no, idx, term) AS (
  SELECT task_seq_no,
         idx, 
         MAX(term)
  FROM   terms
  GROUP BY task_seq_no, idx
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT term) = 1
  AND    COUNT(term) = COUNT(*)
)
SELECT task_seq_no,
       LISTAGG(term, '.') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY idx) AS common_term
FROM   common_terms
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY task_seq_no
         ORDER BY idx
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( ^ term1 termN* )
         DEFINE
           term1 AS idx = 1,
           termN AS idx = PREV(idx + 1)
       )
GROUP BY task_seq_no
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (task_seq_no, value) AS
SELECT 1, '558.02'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, '558.02.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '558.02.02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '558.02.07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '558.02.08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '558.02.06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '555'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '555.01'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '555.04'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '554.02.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '554.03.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '554.04.01' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| TASK_SEQ_NO | COMMON_TERM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 558.02 |
| 2 | 555 |
| 3 | 554 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kst97wG3)